# Python: Select Interpreter command not found in vscode command palette

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have setup a project workspace folder, and I need to setup the interpreter but the command "Python: Select Interpreter" is not found.

Comment: Have you installed the python extension?

Comment: If you already have it installed, try re-installing it. You can also check if you *indeed* have a working Python installation on your machine (ex. correct path, permissions). A quick way to check is opening a console (outside of VS Code), and running a simple Python script.

Comment: Yeah I didn't install it, thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem today. For me, it was a trust problem with the Python Package.

Go to the extensions and type @workspaceUnsupported in the extensions search box at the top of the extensions list.

My Python extension was in the RESTRICTED MODE list.  I trusted the Python extensions and right away a popup showed with the Python: Select Interpreter command which showed me the list of available Python interpreters.

See this link for more information about trusting extensions:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_enabling-extensions

Comment: upvoted - great catch and great help, thnx !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just installed the Python extension on the remote machine (ssh) and it worked for me.